# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, jersey

I have downloaded Jersey Java Rest Api example from
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/post-example.html

When I run this project using 'Run on server', it is accepting the following Rest api commands from Postman and perfectly working fine:

```
GET http://localhost:9900/jaxrs-post-example/rest/customers

POST http://localhost:9900/jaxrs-post-example/rest/customers
{
  "firstName":"David",
  "lastName":"Parker",
  "school":"CSI",
  "standard":"4",
  "rollNumber":85
}
```

When I send same command from ReactJS, the server is showing the following error.

```java
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-json-example-serlvet] in context with path [/JAXRS-JSON] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
```

The code what is used in ReactJS is:

```js
const projectParameters = {
  "id":"2152",
  "name":"David",
  "address":"12,new street",
  "phoneNumber":"8765489011"           
};

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(projectParameters)
};

fetch('http://localhost:9900/JAXRS-JSON/rest/student/data/post',
            requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {                        
                console.log(response);               
            });
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it related to CORS?
2. Please provide solution for this issue.

Comment: This url `http://localhost:9900/JAXRS-JSON/rest/student/data/post` is wrong, it must be existing at your backend, from the above example it appears you only have `http://localhost:9900/jaxrs-post-example/rest/customers`, from where `student/data/post` came?

Comment: Thanks for the notification. Sorry. It is silly typo mistake. Now i am getting CORS error:                     Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9900/jaxrs-post-example/rest/customers' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: you would need to set the cors-header to allow the localhost:3000, try googling it how to do in jersey service, if still cannot search then post a separate question on that.

Comment: I tried in Google. But could not crack. I will raise separate question